# PHP + imap + qresync extension?

Tags: php, email, imap

Is there a way to use IMAP extensions like QRESYNC in PHP?

It seems that the PHP built in IMAP extension does not support it and also packages like ddeboer/imap (https://packagist.org/packages/ddeboer/imap)  or imap/imap (https://packagist.org/packages/ddeboer/imap), which are the most popular packages (according to downloads) on packagist regarding fetching email from an IMAP server, rely on the PHP imap extension and therefore do not support it too. Other popular projects like laminas/mail (https://packagist.org/packages/laminas/laminas-mail) are even more behind in development as they do not even support things like the creation of folders/messages.

I found out that a project called horde (https://dev.horde.org/imap_client/) did their own PHP imap implementation including QRESYNC extension but with the last update in 2014 I wonder if I would bet on a dead horse.

As QRESYNC is quite a necessary extension for building state of the art e-mail functionality in PHP projects (especially web mail clients, etc.) I wonder what do people do? Do they all write their own IMAP implementations like e.g. roundcube (https://roundcube.net/) did (derived from an ancient project called IlohaMail)?

Comment: QRESYNC seems to be old? (https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/qresync/charter/)

Comment: Do you mean it is outdated? If yes, what would be the state-of-the-art replacement for having this functionality?

Comment: As a note of practicality, hardly any servers (especially large commercial servers) support QRESYNC.

Comment: But what is the best practice to get this functionality then? How do PHP mail applications notice when a flag gets changed or a message deleted by another client?

Comment: I generally try to get my PHP application work smoothly with my Dovecot server. As I read, Dovecot supports QRESYNC. I have a mailbox with around 40000 messages. When I connect to the mailbox with Roundcube and delete a message with another client, e.g. Thunderbird, Roundcube will notice at the next refresh of the page within a second. I can't believe that it fetched and compared all 40000 messages that fast.